# Microservice Application ... Docker Volume for Databases or no Docker Volume?

Tags: mongodb, docker, jhipster, rancher

I have an application (JHipster Gateway, UAA, Registry, 5 microservices) and each application source builds a Docker image and pushes to GitLab registry. Currently I'm running everything on Rancher using a Docker-Compose file. My volumes for Mongo databases are currently in each container.

I need advice about volume mounts. Here are my options as I see them.

1. Leave data in containers and monitor and backup
2. Use external mounts and monitor volumes on host.

If I leave Mongo data in the containers, do I just set up to just cluster and when the internal volumes fill, the database just scales? I am looking for some explanation to help my choice with Mongo database mounts, internal or external (on host)?

Thanks in advance,

David L. Whitehurst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never store any data you care about directly in containers.  There are good arguments in favor of both named volumes (native to Docker, some support in a multi-host Swarm environment, fewer host-specific dependencies) and host bind mounts (much easier to back up and maintain, possible to examine directly if needed) but use *some* sort of mounted storage.

The most important note here is that it's fairly routine to delete and recreate containers.  If the software you're running or its underlying library stack has a security issue, you generally need to get (or build) an updated image, delete your existing container, and rebuild it against the new image.  If data is stored only inside a container, then during this very routine delete-and-recreate operation, there's significant risk of losing data.

In principle, if you're really careful, and you have a replicated data store, you can roll this over without external volumes and not lose data.  It's tricky, and takes a lot of patience; you'll be forced to take down one replica, wait for its data to be rebalanced across the other replicas, start up a new replica, wait for it to accept some of the data, and so on.  If you can take a point release by stopping a container, deleting it, starting a new one with the same data store, and have it come up instantly with populated data, that's much easier to manage.

(The other corollary here is that you don't "back up containers", since they don't have any data you care about.  You do back up the data stored on the host or in Docker named volumes, and you can always recreate the container from its image plus the external data.)

Comment: Perfect David! And, I have volumes on my macbook pro when I test a smaller local version of everything. And, I couldn't persist when I did docker-compose down. That's why I use local mounts on my macbook small system conglomerate lol.  Okay so I name the mounts for each database in my docker-compose and then I know what I have no matter what I stand up, take down, scale, etc. Perfect! Thanks. That's exactly what I expected to hear. I am in the beginning stages of a startup but I still want the production footprint early. So I'm testing everything. Thanks again :-)